# How to run a Quartz Scheduler on a previous or next business day

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

[In this article](https://www.javarticles.com/2016/06/quartz-calendar-example.html) it is explained how to exclude Quartz from running on specific calendar days, but what I need is something different, I need to run the job in the previous or next business day if the trigger calendar results on a holiday.

For example, assume the job is scheduled to run monthly, including Friday, 29 March 2019 that is a holiday.

This means that:

- Not Holiday: Thursday, 28 March 2019  (when the job should run if it runs
  *before* holiday)
- Holiday: Friday, 29 March 2019
- Holiday: Saturday, 30 March 2019
- Holiday: Sunday, 31 March 2019
- Not Holiday: Monday, 1 April 2019 (when the job should run if it runs *after* holiday)

One way to achieve this is to run the job every day and analyze whether it should run on that day or not, and retrigger if necessary, but is there a better way?

**UPDATE**

If I have to trigger the job every day, why not use instead the Java EE 8 [TimerService](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ejb/TimerService.html)?

Comment: I would suggest keep, Quartz Scheduler and business logic separate and trigger jobs based on logic in Java. I am not able to understand running job on the previous day?

Comment: Meaning that you would trigger the job every day and have a business logic in Java to see if it runs that day?

Comment: `job is scheduled to run on Friday, 29 March 2019, but it is a holiday.` if it is not ment to run, do not schedule it.

Comment: It is scheduled to run monthly, and it falls on a holiday, that why it's scheduled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to run it on every working day using Cron Expression for example (Running every weekday at 5 PM)

```
0 00 17 * * MON-FRI
```

and Inside a function which gets invoked by Cron expression, you can call holidayService.isHoliday(date) which will tell if the date is a holiday. If it is Holiday then you can skip running the report.

Comment: I don't want to skip the job if it's a holiday, I want to run it the previous or next business day

Comment: This is just an idea. You can schedule accordingly or do whatever you want if it's holiday.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I had to schedule for the third-to-last business day, after some research this turned out to be the correct string:

```
0 45 20 L-3W * ? *
```

the "L-3W" means "third before last weekday (MON-FRI)"